# IE7 z-index not working correctly

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, z-index

I've run into the infamous ie7 z-index bug but none of the solutions I have found on the web have been successful in fixing my problem :/

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/bwLJM/

The green box appears above in all browsers including ie9 and ie8 but not ie7 (i don't care about ie6)

**If I remove the `position:relative;` from the parent element though it will fix the issue but I need that to stay because I am going to be positioning some elements inside a parent of those boxes using absolute!**

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you put the overlay box inside relative positioned element? Like in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/QPjJR/2/)?

It works in my IE7.

Comment: That works :P not an ideal solution as I'm causing a div nested to break out and pretend it's not but that's shitty IE7 for you. Thanks

Comment: That's nice! I learned by experience that the best way to deal with its bugged z-index system is by having nested elements as much as possible and try to stick with those, instead of trying to make different z-index stacks work together.